# Database value not displayed in jsp & jstl file

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, jsp, jstl

I use MYSQL Workbench as the database,I have 3 columns uname,orderdet,ordercost under the orders table.I have to retrieve the values from the database to the jsp webpage for a single user.

details.jsp

```
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql" %>   
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>JSP Cart</title>
</head>
<body>
    <sql:setDataSource var="mydb" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/form" user="root" password="sudhakar" />
    <sql:query dataSource="${mydb}" var="listUsers">select orderdet,ordercost from orders where uname =" <%=session.getAttribute("name") %>"</sql:query>
    <div align="center">
        <table border="1" cellpadding="5">
            <caption><h2>Cart Details</h2></caption>
            <tr>
                <th>order</th>
                <th>ordercost</th>
            </tr>
            <c:forEach var="user" items="${listUsers.rows}">
                <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="${user.orderdet}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${user.ordercost}" /></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
<button><a href="page1.jsp">Go back</a>
</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I wish to show only the orderdetails and the ordercost and not the username and henceforth I removed the uname data in the jsp page.i hope it doesnt cause confusion

Comment: What does the generated HTML look like?